# How to Change Into Real Format Currency

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How to change this code into real format currency from Rp 1000 into Rp 1,000 the $totalBalance is the variable for connecting database

i am want to change this nominal into real formatted currency

```
Here the source code
```

Text(
'\Rp $totalBalance',
style: const TextStyle(
fontSize: 20,
color: AppTheme.darkGray,
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [NumberFormatter.currency](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat.currency.html) from the `intl` package.

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

print(NumberFormat.currency(symbol: 'Rp ').format(1000)); // "Rp 1,000.00"
```